# How to access the "Sort as" field of MPMediaItem?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery, apple-music

iTunes has a way of sorting the songs that the ones with title starts with "a" or "the" are recognized without it. Is there a way to access this "sort title"? I am pretty sure Apple Music does this and I guess it can be accessed by

```
let item = MPMediaItem()
let sortName = item.value(forProperty: "someMagicSortNamePropertyIdentifier") as! String
```

I am talking about this fields in iTunes
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic format for all sort Properties is sortProperty i.e. sortTitle, sortAlbumTitle, sortAlbumArtist etc.

```
func sortProperty(for property: String) -> String{
    return "sort" + property.prefix(1).uppercased() + property.dropFirst()
}
```

Comment: It works. You can't imagine how helpful this is, thank you so much!

Comment: One thing to note is the property would have `nil` if the value is not set, so fallback to actual property if the value is `nil`.

Comment: Bummer, I tried sortArtist and sortAlbumArtist on iOS 14 and it just crashes. Apparently it's not available anymore.

Comment: I just checked, it’s still working fine on my end. I’m guessing you might have used NSObject’s valueForKey instead of MPMediaEntity’s valueForProperty method. Using valueForKey could lead to this crash.